# Redirections with commands other then cat

Tags: c, shell, unix

I'm working on a personal shell and started implementing redirections.

'<' works just fine and '>' only works for the cat command.

Here is the code that handles the effect of '>' :

```
int     write_in_file(char **tab, int fd)
{
  int   count;
  char   i;

  if (strncmp("cat", tab[0], 3) == 0)
    {
      while ((count = read(0, &i, 1)) > 0)
        write(fd, &i, 1);
      exit(1);
    }
  else if (strncmp("ls", tab[0], 2) == 0)
    {
      /* Here handle other commands then cat */
    }
  else
    return (0);
}
```

As you can see, when the shell recognizes

```
cat > file
```

It does what it is supposed to do : let the user write into the said file.
But now I wish to handle other commands such as

```
ls > file
man ascii > file
```

Do you guys have any idea how I could do it? 
If you need any precisions, please let me know,

EDIT : Note that I am in the child process while in this function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you `exit(1)` when your code 'works just fine'?  An exit status of 1 indicates failure.

Comment: Man `fork`, `exec`,  or google fork/exec

Comment: You are absolutely right, I will change that right away.

Comment: And I am in the child process when in this function by the way.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement `cat`?  (You are not implementing -u correctly, as required by http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html#tag_20_13).  Instead of implementing the tool, you should simply `exec`.  What you need to do is dup the appropriate file descriptor on to the redirected path and call `exec`.

Comment: I understand, but I am only allowed to use execve, after a dup2(1, fd) how do I use it with the appropriate file descriptor?

Comment: Use `dup2` to make stdout (file descriptor 1) of the child be associated with the file.  When you `exec` (and by that I mean when you call any of `exec`, `execl`, `execv`, `execvp`, etc.) the child will be writing to that file.

Answer (score 0):

## How I/O redirections work

When the shell calls `exec` (to start e.g.cat or man), the program will inherit all file handles that have been set up before. The programm will use 0 as stdin, 1 as stdout, 2 as stderr. If you want to redirect output to a file, you will have open your output file and use `dup2` to set it up as file number 1. Usually all of this is done after a `fork`.

See [GNU C Library: Duplicating Descriptors](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Duplicating-Descriptors.html#Duplicating-Descriptors) and [GNU C Library: Launching jobs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Launching-Jobs.html#Launching-Jobs)

## Other tools you may need

You should not use `strncmp(command, "cat", 3)` to check if the command is cat, because this will also match for catman or catdvi, but not for " cat". Instead use a tokenizer, e.g. `strtok`.

See [The Gnu C Library: Finding Tokens in a String](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html#Finding-Tokens-in-a-String)

Comment: The first part of  your answer is good. The second part not as much, because the OP shouldn't be checking the command name at all.

Comment: @JohnKugelman you are right, a shell should not care about the command name at that point, but at some point a shell will have to parse a command line and also identify built-in commands. Implementing cat as a built-in is probably not the first thing you would do when writing your own shell from scratch, however shells do have built-in commands (e.g. echo, test, true, cd, help) and probably do so for good reasons.